# threads with different priority levels

Tags: pthreads

I am trying to make two threads (`t1` and `t2`) each with a different priority level (`priority1` and `priority2`).

`t1` runs `First_thread()` and `t2` runs `Second_thread()`. Each job is simply running a counter.

The program shows no error but when I try to execute; the message says:

> Thread 1 cannot run

The code is:

```
pthread_attr_t attr1;
struct sched_param  priority1;
pthread_attr_t attr2;
struct sched_param  priority2;

pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr1, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, SCHED_FIFO);

priority1.sched_priority = 10;
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &priority1);

pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr2, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);   
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr2, SCHED_FIFO);

priority2.sched_priority = 9;
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr2, &priority2);

if (pthread_create(&t1, &attr1, First_thread, NULL)) {
    printf("ERROR CANNOT START First Thread\n");
    return 0;
}

if (pthread_create(&t2, &attr2, Second_thread, NULL)){ 
    printf("ERROR CANNOT START First Thread\n");    
    return 0; 
}

pthread_join(t1, NULL);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr1);
pthread_join(t2, NULL);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr2);
```

Comment: Can you copy past your complete code ?

Comment: In the main I defined the two threads t1 and t2 with the task they must do:                                                                                   void *First_thread()
{
 //local vars declared//
 struct timespec time1;
 int gperiod1=100;
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time1);       
 time_add_ms(&time1, gperiod1);

 do {
  //do something here; like a simple text display on screen 
// now to make it periodic i am doing the time stamp stuff
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,TIMER_ABSTIME, &time1, NULL);  
time_add_ms(&time1, gperiod1);
} while((!key[KEY_ESC]));
}

Comment: similarly I defined the other tast for tw in void *Second thread() {some period task with time stamp and stuff}

Comment: Now I call both the threads from the main.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add lrt library path to eclipse c++ in ubunto? I have come to know its because of the library path is not added?

Comment: @ sik
 in eclipse look into the project properties , c/c++ build ->Settings->Gcc Linker->Libraries in that -l add name and  Path -L at down

Comment: @Mohan. Thanks man. I found what I was supposed to do. The code is perfect, I just needed to run the code as a Super User with extra privileges.